# Latex code is not working in preview?

Tags: discussion

Latex code is not working in preview so i am asking a question to see if it really works.

\frac{a}{b}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `\frac{a}{b}` is just a code fragment. I see no reason to expect it to do anything at all. Please be *a lot more specific* as to what you've tried so far; a claim such as "code is not working in preview" is simply not actionable. Also, please do explain what you set the tag "latex3". Separately, you may wish to peruse the information available in the posting [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5001)

Comment: There is no preview of LaTeX code on tex.stackexchange, for good reasons. This was discussed on meta somewhere.